# how to use draggable and double click together in kineticjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kineticjs

how to use draggable and double click together in kineticjs?
when using draggable then double click will not work.
Here is my code to draw the image..

```
  function draw(images) {
       abcImg= new Kinetic.Rect({
       x: 50,
       y: 150,
       width: 50,
       height: 50,
       fillPatternImage: images.abc,
       name: "abc",
       draggable: true
   });
 }
```

and here the code when double click..

```
  layer.on('dblclick', function(evt) {
    var shape = evt.shape;
    name = shape.getName();

    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );

  });
```

I'm use kineticjs and jquery.. Thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is how to listen for mouse/touch events on the empty areas of the stage.**

To listen for mouse/touch events on the stage (any non-object area), you need to add a new layer containing a rectangle that fills the stage.  Then you can handle mouse/touch events on the empty stage areas:  eventLayer.on(“dblclick”,function(e) {//do doubleclick stuff}

That layer code looks like this:

```
  // Create a layer that will listen for mouse/touch events
  var eventLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
  eventLayer.add(new Kinetic.Rect({
  x:0,
  y:0,
  width:400,
  height:300
  }));
  stage.add(eventLayer);

  // TEST--listen for "dblclick"
  eventLayer.on('dblclick', function(evt) {
    alert("2click");
  });
```

Here is the full code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/gNMRq/

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/kinetic-v4.3.2-beta.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>

    <script>
      var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 400,
        height: 300
      });
      var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
      var rectX = stage.getWidth() / 2 - 50;
      var rectY = stage.getHeight() / 2 - 25;

      var box = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: rectX,
        y: rectY,
        width: 100,
        height: 50,
        fill: '#00D2FF',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4,
        draggable: true
      });

      // add cursor styling
      box.on('mouseover', function() {
        document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
      });
      box.on('mouseout', function() {
        document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
      });

      // Create a layer that will listen for mouse/touch events
      var eventLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
      eventLayer.add(new Kinetic.Rect({
      x:0,
      y:0,
      width:400,
      height:300
      }));
      stage.add(eventLayer);

      // TEST--listen for "dblclick"
      eventLayer.on('dblclick', function(evt) {
        alert("2click");
      });

      layer.add(box);
      stage.add(layer);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for helping me. I know what is the problem now. It's because the version of kineticjs.

Answer (score 1):

it is working fine. Take a look at this, it's using draggable and dblclick, and both works fine.

http://jsbin.com/oruhif/1/edit